# SQL statement (for loop) with SUM from other table

Tags: sql

[image: sample image]

I have 2 tables: **STORES** & **REPORTS**. The common key is the **store_id**
See attached image...

I want to build an SQL statement in a way to give me the total (SUM) of **daily sales**, **daily visits** and **daily questions** for each store separately.

Is there any way to do that, in a way that I will be able to loop through (move.next) in each store so to have the totals of each one store in one line?

Comment: For future questions: please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query --

```
select 
    s.store_name,
    sum(r.[daily sales]) as [daily sales], 
    sum(r.[daily visits]) as [daily visits],
    sum(r.[daily questions]) as [daily questions] 
from 
    stores s 
left outer join 
    reports r on s.stored_id = r.store_id
group by 
    s.store_name
```